# Control Layout Rendering from Child Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout page and, for the moment, one page that uses that layout.  I would like to have a portion of the page that can be shown or hidden at the child pages discretion.  If it is hidden, then other style changes, like the width of the main content div, need to be adjusted.  Below is my **non-working** attempt at this:

**Layout page**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.ShowTree = true;
}

<div class="row">
    @if(ViewBag.ShowTree){
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.Action("ItemTree")
    </div>
    }
    <div class="@(ViewBag.ShowTree ? "col-md-10" : "col-md-12")">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

**Child Page**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NestedLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.ShowTree = false;
}
```

In this instance the value for ShowTree is set to true, the layout page renders, and then the child sets it to false and the content renders.  This makes perfect sense based on the page life cycle for MVC. But of course is not how I want it to work.

I know I could set this value in the controller, and not set it in the layout/web page at all, but I'd like to have this be purely a design thing if I can and keep it out of the controller.

My preference would be for it to not call the action at all, and not just hide the data with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I like your approach, but if that doesn't work, the only other mechanism I can think where the child view can control the layout would be using `@section`. Not ideal, but should work.

Layout page:

```
<div class="row">
    @RenderSection("ItemTreeSection", required: false)

    <div class="@(ViewBag.ShowTree ? "col-md-10" : "col-md-12")">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Child view:

```
@section ItemTreeSection {
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.Action("ItemTree")
    </div>
}
```

Comment: So I would have to use both a section and a flag... Not ideal, but it would probably work I suppose.

Comment: Arghhh, I didn't notice your were also using the flag to show the different grid column. Now I'm not liking my solution.